# Blurry text for all non system application in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, wayland, scaling

I have laptop and external display, to make display work properly I have to turn on fractional scaling and all was set. But when I opened chrome, vs code and other apps, text were stretched. I searched online but nothing worked for all apps.

Temporarily I enabled Preferred Ozone platform to Wayland to make chrome work
for vs code I turn on wayland by editing it's Desktop file (after very update I have to update it again)
Still there are other applications like postman were I wasn't able to find solution.

here is the resolutions I have:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3360 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 190mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Also I have edited /etc/fonts/conf.d/ file to turn Wayland to true but didn't work.
(I am new to Ubuntu)

Please help to fix this, thanks in advance